# Как найти корень сайта?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как опредлить, где находится корень сайта? Сайт находится на хостинге, я им только начала заниматься, там очень много файлов и папок, страницы сайта полностью генерируются скриптами php и я никак не могу разобраться, какой скрипт первым начинает работу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] - корень
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/index.php' - обычно начинается с него если в .htaccess не указано иначе
```

Comment: Мне надо именно определить папку, кот. является корнем сайта, т.е. путь к корню, файл .HTACCESS тоже не могу найти.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы найти корень сайта, нужно знать конфигурацию сервера, на котором бежит РНР.
В принципе, всю подноготную установок, которыми пользуется РНР можно узнать, если запустить файл РНР с коммандой phpinfo();
Там будет написано, полный путь к корневой директории, какие файлы понимает РНР, и какой файл вызывается по умолчанию, если вообще таковой есть.

Comment: Спасибо, но я даже не могу там запустить файл, т.к. для этого тоже надо знать, куда его положить, что бы он запустился.

Comment: Ну если есть доступ к административной панели хостинга - то там то написано какая директория является домашней

Comment: Нет, доступа нет. Постараюсь получить тогда. Спасибо.